# How to set Nest Thermostat to control blower without heat

Tags: fans, nest, blower, lennox

I have a Lennox G14Q3 propane furnace (forced air). I used the Nest/furnace setup last winter without any problems with just the W and R terminals. 
But, these summer days I would like to push air through the house with the blower (without heat) and remove it with my HRV system.

I’ve tried hooking up the terminal G to the G terminal on the Nest (for the fan). But the Nest can’t seem to turn it on.

Note: When I test the heat with the Nest, my furnace goes through it’s standard cycle of heating up then turning on the blower.

Also, I can’t seem to get the blower going down at the furnace by shorting R and G, shouldn’t that work?

Thanks,
Josh

Edit, added model and diagram pictures:
[image]

[image]

**EDIT 2:**
I realized that ACC isn't actually connected to anything. It gets 120VAC when I switch the relay, but there is still no path to the blower to be energized. 
Could I just take one of the speed wires from the blower motor and connect it to ACC so that it acts as an indoor blower?
[image]

Comment: Do you get 120V from ACC to N when you jumper G to R on the furnace?

Comment: Did you re-do the initialization cycle with the Nest where it discovers what kind of heater it's attached to, and what features it has?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I get the standard 24VAC between G and R, until of course when I short them.

Comment: @Harper yes, the Nest detected the W, R and G lines. C isn’t connected, but when I did connect it, the Nest didn’t boot. I’ve read that’s because it detects incorrect wiring

Comment: @JoshJobin -- can you measure the voltage from ACC to N while G and R are shorted together?

Comment: Also, what's the resistance between G and C while the G terminal is open?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel where would I measure ACC? Would I need to remove another cover? I know it has power because it sparks and hums a little, but maybe it doesn’t have sufficient power?

Comment: ACC should be available from the 120V terminal block on your control board (right next to where the incoming hot and neutral connect to the control board)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I am not home at the moment, but I’ll measure it later. Another couple facts, when I press “manual fan” on the furnace, it runs continuously. Also, when the Nest activates the heat, the fan comes on normally once the furnace is up to heat

Comment: Also, was your furnace subject to the [recall](https://inspectapedia.com/heat/Lennox_Pulse_Furnace_Notice.php)?  Has it had the heat exchanger replaced with the modified unit already?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel the voltage is 120VAC, and the resistance between G and C is 7.4MegaOhm

Comment: @JoshJobin -- did you see my link re: the recall?

Comment: I did, but I have only lived in this house for 1 year. I image the owners before me (who are the original owners) got it inspected. If not, I also have a CO detector in my basement.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I made an edit, could I just connect ACC to one of the other wires used for speed control on the motor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I figured out why it wasn't working. Had nothing to do with ACC not having a lead.
I was looking at my setup closely and noticed that only 2 wires were coming up from the motor, but it needs 3. 
I noticed that there was a wire coming from pin 3, but it was crimped and didn't run to the motor. So I looked at the speed table and decided I wanted to run the Brown wire up. Connected it to pin 3. Now when I short R and G, the fan turns on :) 
[image]

Comment: That'd do it :) BTW: you probably should replace this furnace soon -- there's no telling if the previous owners did anything re: the recall, and HX leaks in furnaces are something that's way better to be safe than sorry about.  At a bare minimum, I'd have the HX pressure tested ASAP as per Lennox's instructions on the matter.